# C# throwing dice method

Tags: c#

I need two methods. The first method throws four dice and returns the dice sum. The second method estimates the sum and print "excellent" if the sum is greater than 20, "good" if the sum is greater 12 or sum is less than or equal to 20 and "poor" if the sum is less than or equal to 12.

The dice are thrown by writing the rows

```
Random ran = new Random ();
int throwingdice = ran.nextInt(1,7);
```

i tried many times but it wont work, any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what did you try ? homework flag ? there is no problem helping you with your homework, but at least give it a try

Comment: What's the exact problem your encountering? You should be specific as to what is not working.

Comment: What hardware do you have to throw and read the dice?

Comment: i'm not in a school, i want just learn c#

Comment: `throw` is a keyword, you need another variable name to start with

Comment: What have you tried? Is there no code to look at so we can show where it is going wrong?

Comment: You know you have spelt your account name wrong, or is it meant to be like that ;)

Comment: `throw` is a keyword in C#, rename your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help you get started...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();

            int sum=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var roll = r.Next(1, 7);
                sum += roll;
            }
            // sum should be the sum of the four dices
            Console.WriteLine("the sum of the first 4 throws is {0}", sum);

            if (sum > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("place your message in here stating that sum gas greater than 20");
            }
            else if (sum < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("sum is less than 10");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("some other message");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should rename your variable "throw", because throw has a special meaning in C#, like for,each,int etc.
2. here's an example for using random():

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Threading;

   public class RandomNumbers
   {
       public static void Main()
       {
          Random rand1 = new Random();
          Random rand2 = new Random();
          Thread.Sleep(2000);
          Random rand3 = new Random();
          ShowRandomNumbers(rand1);
          ShowRandomNumbers(rand2);
          ShowRandomNumbers(rand3);
       }

       private static void ShowRandomNumbers(Random rand)
       {
         Console.WriteLine();
         byte[] values = new byte[5];
         rand.NextBytes(values);
         foreach (byte value in values)
            Console.Write("{0, 5}", value);
         Console.WriteLine();   
       }
   }
   // The example displays the following output to the console:
   //       28   35  133  224   58
   //    
   //       28   35  133  224   58
   //    
   //       32  222   43  251   49
   ```

   Source:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/h343ddh9.aspx

Comment: when you edit your code you should see helpers at the top. or you can just indent your code to format it...

Comment: i have tried that already... the formation get's totally mixed up and weird then

Comment: make sure you indent it enough. placing about 20 spaces before each line should do the trick. if you dont indent it enough it is not going to work. copy your code from visual studio or whatever your ide is after you past it on the editor of stackoverflow select it and click on the {} button that should be at the top of the text area editor...

Comment: thanks, i had to add much more than the usual 4 spaces, then it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what is the purpose of the second method when all that you want can be achieved in one method as shown by Tono Nam. You can simply add a switch statement or an if else block to output your string value.

```
public void yourMethod()
{
    Random r = new Random(); 

    int sum=0;       

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)         
    {             
        var roll = r.Next(1, 7);             
        sum += roll;         
    }         // sum should be the sum of the four dices 


    //a switch is faster for a larger amount of options
    switch(sum)
    {
        case 20:
        {
            Console.WriteLine("excellent");
        }
    }

    //Or use If else
    if(sum>=20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("excellent");
    }
}
```

Just an example and would have to be built up.